# Save cookie and User Data

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

the following code makes a list of your current cookie on a web page.

```
from selenium import webdriver
w = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)
w.get("https://www.example.com/")
listx = w.get_cookies()
print(listx)
```

How can I save this kind of data as a folder to reuse as user data? Like here.

I share a screen shot an example the cookie folder.
[image]